# $.post not working in latest firefox but works in all other browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, post

I have this jquery that gets called when user clicks the continue button:

```
<script type="text/javascript">     
        function register()  
        {   
            $.post("<?php echo site_url('register'); ?>", {
                    email: $('#email').val(), 
                    storename: $('#storename').val(), 
                    password: $('#password').val()
            }, 
            function(data){ alert('testingdfgf');
                var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data); 
                alert(obj.message);
                if(obj.result === 'success'){
                    document.location.href="<?php echo site_url('activationpage'); ?>";
                }
            });
        }        
    </script>
```

The function call works in all other major browsers 100% correctly, but in firefox it does nothing.  I know its the $.post method thats the issue, but not sure why its causing a problem.  Any ideas?

Comment: What happens in firefox?  Nothing at all?  Any errors?

Comment: you created `function register()` from where you are calling it?

Comment: nope in firebug no php or server related or even javascript related errors show up in the console...

Comment: from a button on that page.  But again, the button to the javasscript function is linked and works correctly, but its the $.post that is not working.

Comment: you want it to redirect to other page ? if yes then why you are using `===` ? it should be `if(obj.result == 'success') {`

Comment: no thats not the issue.  My issue is that the $.post method is breaking or causing an error, but not sure why.  If you put an alert call before the $.post call, it shows the alert, but if you put it in the call back function of the $.post method, it doesn't work, meaning its the $.post method thats the issue.

Comment: oh then give try to `$.ajax` and use `success` function

Comment: @user1832892: Have you set up an error handler?

Comment: @AspiringAqib: That's pointless. You know what `$.post` is doing? Have a look in the source code.

Comment: i just told u, its the $.post method thats not working only in firefox.  If it did work, all the code in it works fine.  But for some reason the its not working in firefox, and the location object is not the issue...

Comment: hey @Bergi he says it shows alert then it is also pointless to use error handler. well, in other way error handler helps alot

Comment: geez why do browsers have to be sooo  annoying like this...i mean compatibility issues are just such a waste of time.

Comment: @AspiringAqib: even though it won't make a difference here, there are very few places where you "want" to use `==`. There is no reason to use it here.

Comment: @user1832892: Check Firebugs network inspector. Is the request started, how does it resolve? Btw, `jQuery.parseJSON` should not be necessary if you had used an appropriate content type.

Comment: @JimDeville that was my former deal and you didn't noticed my latter one . . .

Comment: @AspiringAqib: I noticed all of your comments, none of them correct the idea of using '==' instead of '===', so I brought that up

Comment: @JimDeville you voted the below answer?

Comment: @AspiringAqib: no, because he's not getting into the callback so changing from `document.location` to `window.location` won't make a difference. @user1832892: You need to add an error handler (via chaining a `.error(function() { console.log(arguments) }` or using `.complete`) or you should use the network inspector to see if you are getting a failure response for some reason here. `$.post` doesn't throw an error on failure last time I checked.

Comment: @JimDeville i can't understand you all, if you have READ previous comments, the questioner wrote it gives alert. so, adding error handler will not help, as his `$.post` request always be completed and `$.post` function will not transfer control to error handler function.

Comment: Actually, he said the exact opposite "If you put an alert call before the $.post call, it shows the alert, but if you put it in the call back function of the $.post method, it doesn't work, meaning its the $.post method thats the issue". IOW, no alert from the callback, which implies the callback isn't happening.

Comment: yes, thanks Jim Deville...if the call back isnt happening that means the $.post function is having an error when either sending the request, or recieving, but i know for a fact on the server the function request is properlly handled for an ajax request.  That much is for sure.

Comment: @user18328982: Right, so adding a handler, or looking at the response in Firebug, should help you find the cause. It sounds like you might be hitting an error between the raw XHR object, and the post callback, which should still trigger an error, or complete handler, even if the response _should_ be a success (i.e. even if response is HTTP 200).

Answer (score 2):

Try **`window.location`** instead. It works fine in all browsers.

```
window.location = "<?php echo site_url('activationpage'); ?>";
```

Comment: umm i don't think thats the issue, the issue is when $.post is making it's call, something wrong is happening there, not the code in the callback function.

Comment: can't you just check it ? I also gave the MOZ documentation link and you said no no its not problem, there must be problem with the thing @OnurYILDIRIM pointed out bcoz jQuery `$.post` supports each and every browser

Comment: -1 As I pointed out in the comments, he isn't hitting the alerts, so the contents of the callback are probably not the problem.

Comment: I wrote the answer before or ignoring those comments. It is not indicated in the question.